# Get the middle ID after the "com/ in the url string below in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ts-jest

I would like to extract the middle ID from below string

const url  = "https://state.velon.com/11eb35c9-3c69-e7f2-a4eb-0ac9483cdf87/reports/corporate";

And I want to grab the middle ID = "11eb35c9-3c69-e7f2-a4eb-0ac9483cdf87" from the string

Should I just use substring and index of or are there other ways of doing that. Please help

Comment: Use the built-in [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the built-in [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) api is probably the canonical way and the safest way to do it:

```js
const urlString = "https://state.velon.com/11eb35c9-3c69-e7f2-a4eb-0ac9483cdf87/reports/corporate";

const url = new URL(urlString);

console.log(url.pathname.split("/")[1]);
```

URLs can get pretty crazy, so we should just rely on the built-in way to parse it for us :)